# Sharing user ID's as a way to find people

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it safe to share a user's ID that Firebase creates when a new user is created? I'd like to use it as an easy way to find other people on my platform.
I don't see why it should not be safe, so if it is. Please enlighten me :)

Comment: Can you provide more details on the system you are building?

Comment: It's just a system that needs a way to find friends. So I wanted to take the Nintendo route and work with Friend Codes. But is it safe to use user IDs as the Friend Codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with your system or how Nintendo does this (not really a gamer) but you can build something like this:

You can display the list of users (using `uid`, `displayName` and `photoURL` which can be obtained using the Admin SDK or by a list you maintain in the Firebase Database, Firestore, etc) to an authenticated user.
Let's say that user wants to add a connection or friend, you can get that user's ID token, the friend's `uid` and then add that user's `uid` to that authenticated user's pending connection list after you verify their ID token.
On the other end, you want the other user to accept the connection request (assuming this how your people finder feature works in your app). You would show the list of pending requests. When the user accepts the request, they would send their ID token and once that's verified, you can consider the connection completed.

To summarize, you still need an ID token to confirm the user sending the request and the one confirming it. Otherwise, if you just solely rely on `uids`, any user can get the `uid` of other users and try to add them to each other's friends list, etc.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Any one may add any one, so that isn't a problem. But what I'm getting from this is that there is no security problem in making user IDs public?

Comment: If any one can add any one and no user has to explicitly accept or initiate the request, then exposing `uids` is fine.